# Node FS read file extracting specific string

Tags: node.js, file, readfile, fs

Hi so here is my question i have a large network log that im logging using chrome I have included a small portion of what the log file looks like with the information i need to extract.

```
{"pid":2748,"tid":11624,"ts":345045004582,"ph":"I","cat":"devtools.timeline","name":"TimerInstall","s":"t","tts":175817,"args":{"data":{"timerId":3,"timeout":30000.0,"singleShot":true,"stackTrace":[{"functionName":"t.sendFetchRequest","scriptId":"12","url":"https://cvp.twitch.tv/2.17.2/wasmworker.min.js","lineNumber":1,"columnNumber":13925}]}}},
{"pid":2748,"tid":11624,"ts":345045004782,"ph":"I","cat":"devtools.timeline","name":"ResourceSendRequest","s":"t","tts":175969,"args":{"data":{"requestId":"2748.61","frame":"","url":"https://video-weaver.jfk04.hls.ttvnw.net/v1/playlist/CpkEmldXq0KjmFA-Mh5knkt1wdu0JKTUHWlvqmba3F2A20pXKynTgazmqtVdJFYUc_IgRCofliiy9UPE-FPDpwyfwOu6yjkomOty7YNCtE3Ax4myL0Z2va45aW5aPGMkn2ttEWxyUmrLVYC3EZ_e7Wxv6x1oHQB3RSUiiKjOYUBweG1nX3kUamZVsN4kmX5j7YZ3O8z1jAJpNGXNPrr1ADorCctWgefnAtrn4vgIbaiQaTaF0JXUfe7UII98YFpmwIiml6jVj2G9iRB25m2Uux6uMW47YnPGclgVKlLRWWutyJGTZsvco54cTqmzOSJO8drmAlJO3fjejbIXo9UIgHzHIt5DAqrleJ-VZek8L1-D6m9cpDWGGIx6JLedvbqy5uYHj2mhXqfZdlkSL_cq0JrgyDtGt8Y9UmHXERVPTGpGAo82x6EOepIc-XKUw83zdE4HtAjawn2NxJV0lIBa5GENTM1eh70PYVBZDD8x5y2DOkqbUl3iMjVgnCm1fmO-VihwajZJ2lzgy9A2pS683cTcWDw0eRuovRERQJ6rS45i2oJE0a0W4SZuziTCN8eqbWrXioh5nTVwbI7P1QIL7VBjK0552od_xq4fe9Xmxt_pRBfqiRabe4C6VbE_qsUCcLb0Yg_2RXxOESodx90kjW7ZaJxMlPcxk_koilhXudqn5GA3HIUfAmmwg7wQjL-iv2Rswq5PyVW1Z9x1EhBpkHOjQ9D6awqbs-jC0vwJGgxBHDSR_4FUU6cLBjs.m3u8","requestMethod":"GET","priority":"High","stackTrace":[{"functionName":"t.sendFetchRequest","scriptId":"12","url":"https://cvp.twitch.tv/2.17.2/wasmworker.min.js","lineNumber":1,"columnNumber":14017}]}}},
{"pid":2748,"tid":11624,"ts":345045005497,"ph":"X","cat":"v8.execute","name":"V8.HandleInterrupts","dur":5,"tdur":3,"tts":176545,"args":{}},
{"pid":2748,"tid":11624,"ts":345045005738,"ph":"I","cat":"devtools.timeline","name":"TimerRemove","s":"t","tts":176767,"args":{"data":{"timerId":2,"stackTrace":[{"functionName":"","scriptId":"12","url":"https://cvp.twitch.tv/2.17.2/wasmworker.min.js","lineNumber":1,"columnNumber":15401}]}}},
{"pid":2748,"tid":11624,"ts":345045005772,"ph":"E","cat":"v8.execute","name":"RunMicrotasks","tts":176793,"args":{"microtask_count":7}},
```

this is a small portion of the data that is logged but in the json that is logged you will see this line 
`https://video-weaver.jfk04.hls.ttvnw.net/v1/playlist/CpkEmldXq0KjmFA-Mh5knkt1wdu0JKTUHWlvqmba3F2A20pXKynTgazmqtVdJFYUc_IgRCofliiy9UPE-FPDpwyfwOu6yjkomOty7YNCtE3Ax4myL0Z2va45aW5aPGMkn2ttEWxyUmrLVYC3EZ_e7Wxv6x1oHQB3RSUiiKjOYUBweG1nX3kUamZVsN4kmX5j7YZ3O8z1jAJpNGXNPrr1ADorCctWgefnAtrn4vgIbaiQaTaF0JXUfe7UII98YFpmwIiml6jVj2G9iRB25m2Uux6uMW47YnPGclgVKlLRWWutyJGTZsvco54cTqmzOSJO8drmAlJO3fjejbIXo9UIgHzHIt5DAqrleJ-VZek8L1-D6m9cpDWGGIx6JLedvbqy5uYHj2mhXqfZdlkSL_cq0JrgyDtGt8Y9UmHXERVPTGpGAo82x6EOepIc-XKUw83zdE4HtAjawn2NxJV0lIBa5GENTM1eh70PYVBZDD8x5y2DOkqbUl3iMjVgnCm1fmO-VihwajZJ2lzgy9A2pS683cTcWDw0eRuovRERQJ6rS45i2oJE0a0W4SZuziTCN8eqbWrXioh5nTVwbI7P1QIL7VBjK0552od_xq4fe9Xmxt_pRBfqiRabe4C6VbE_qsUCcLb0Yg_2RXxOESodx90kjW7ZaJxMlPcxk_koilhXudqn5GA3HIUfAmmwg7wQjL-iv2Rswq5PyVW1Z9x1EhBpkHOjQ9D6awqbs-jC0vwJGgxBHDSR_4FUU6cLBjs.m3u8`

I need to extract this specific url from the data that is logged it will always end with `.m3u8` file extension and begin with  `https://video-weaver.jfk04.hls.ttvnw.net/v1/playlist/`

Thank you for your time stackoverflow community

Comment: Sounds like you could do this with the ready-made tool `grep`.  If you're going to code it yourself, you probably just read the file line by line using the [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) interface and then examine each line to see if it contains what you want (perhaps with a regex).

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution

````
    if(line.includes('https://video-weaver.jfk04.hls.ttvnw.net/v1/playlist/')){
        const urlRegex = /https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/ig
        const matchedUrls = line.match(urlRegex);
        console.log(matchedUrls[0])
    }```
````